# Grails <r:use> and <r:require>

Tags: grails, gsp

I am just curious, what is the difference between `<r:use module=""/>` and
 `<r:require module="" />` ?
They seem to work the same, or are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/ref/Tags/use.html):

> r:use Tag
>
> This tag is deprecated, please see require.